# Magento iframe Checkout, NEED ASSITANCE

Tags: php, magento

On the /checkout/#shipping, How to call another Service and pause before gointo /checkout/#payment
Once we build our Shopping Cart and Add Shipping Address:
/checkout/#shipping

Where is the Controller for OnePage Checkout, that build all the cart information to make the Payload JSOn to go to payment.

Anh how would we write in PHP to Call a Service on another Server.
Have the service Run. then once completed. It will make call to PAge or Script and out URL it complies.

Pretty Much I am trying to use the IFRAM Payment methond in Magento, by encrypting the Shipping / Shopping Cart before Payment (which is the Iframe URL needs to be loaded in)

Please advise

Comment: Please confirm magento version 1 or 2 ? Also add code in your question that you have tried.

Comment: This is version 2.1.9 CE version.

Comment: I dont have any code to add. I am trying to figure out oif there is a Plugin that will allow building the Order CArt to a post to Iframe and we  have to do is style the iFrame and send our encrypoted src to iframe to go to payment get way.